# ngrx selector and derived state

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I have a store that I've created a selector over for some small part of it. I am then coming up with some derived state based on a filter that I want to use elsewhere.

I retrieve my data from a web service call, so when the `firstRedThing$` filter is used, it has no values as the call has yet to return. When `things$` is populated, firstRedThing$ does not seem to be re-evaluated. What am I missing?

```
@Select('mystore.things')
public things$: Observable<Thing[]>
...
this.firstRedThing$ = things$
.pipe(
      map(things => things.filter(t => t.color == 'red')),
      flatMap(t => t),
      first());
```

Comment: It does not solve your problem, but I think that you should remove the call to `flatMap`. It sounds to me as wrong.

Comment: I would guess that it is the `first()` operator which will complete the stream after the first value goes through it. You could add a filter to remove a null or empty array so that the first value to hit the `first()` operator is the actual data.